# Key Pressed Event

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, keylistener

I want add a **KeyEventListener** to **JButton** which responds to Enter key, using following code segment:

```
   private void jButton3KeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
        if (evt.getKeyCode() == 10) {
           eventRegister();
        }
   }
```

I pressed space bar instead of enter and the if condition set to true and the `eventRegister` invoked. Why? How could I prevent this  manner?

Comment: Could you check if [[this](http://pastebin.com/AMBT3q4s)] works for you?  If it does then please post [[SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)] that we could use to reproduce your problem.

Comment: what happens when you press other keys? other than space and enter?

Comment: Dear Pshemo your code is same as mine. I can't understand what's the difference between yours and mine!

Comment: Dear Tala it's ok for other keys. Nothing happens.

Comment: @zari It is just a test if you used your code in correct/expected way. So could you be so kind and answer my question from my previous comment?

Comment: 1) For Swing, typically use key bindings over the AWT based, lower level, `KeyListener`.  See [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for details on how to use them. 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Wow. Pshemo your code works correctly. Why? Really what's the reason? Please post your answer in answer section(not comment) so I can accept it as correct answer.

Comment: @zari little advice: when you write comments to someone write it this way `@userName massage` just like I did in this comment. It will create notification icon in user inbox about your comment. Right now I didn't know that you created massage for me, it was pure luck that I still had tab with this question opened till now :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- don't to use `KeyListener` or `MouseListener` for `JButton` or `JButtons JComponent`, those events are implemented in API, or `ButtonsModel`, every can be testable, with to `consume()` of `KeyEvent`
- `JButton` has implemented [ENTER and SPACE key as accelator in KeyBindings](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/key-bindings/)
- remove `SPACE` from `KeyBindings`, but not suggest that, I'm wouldn'd be confuse users, sure depends of

Answer (score 1):

You should use [KeyBinding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) instead of KeyListeners.

---

But even if you are not, your current code should work like in this example.

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
JButton button=new JButton("do something");
button.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent evt) {
                if (evt.getKeyCode() == 10) {
                        System.out.println("it is ten");
                }
        }
});
frame.getContentPane().add(button);


frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setSize(300, 300);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

If you wont post complete (but short) example that can be used to reproduce your problem it will be almost impossible to say what you did wrong.

(I will try to edit this answer if you add more informations about your code).

Comment: `KeyListener` is not meant to be used with Swing (as they are far too low level), [KeyBinding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) is the way to go. Of all the people, you are the one who can see the deleted posts and comments, a person with your `reputation` should not be emphasizing on the bad practices :( -1 for that :(

Comment: @nIcEcOw I agree that KeyBinding is correct way here and OP already knows that based on other answers, but this doesn't change a fact that behaviour in OP question is unusual so was trying to show how (although it is not best way) this should work. My plan was to make OP post more code that would let me locate root of his problem so I could use it as argument to show why KeyBindings ware better,  easier and less error prone.

Comment: I hope that works out well :-) upvoted it this time, KEEP SMILING :-)

Answer (score 0):

try to use

```
if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
....
```

> "Key pressed" and "key released" events are lower-level and depend on the platform and keyboard layout.

Since java is cross platform, don't use hardcoded values for keyboard codes.

Comment: strange, wroks on my machine. also found source code confirming it http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0253.html

Comment: @Tala : Again KeyListeners are not used with Swing, instead [KeyBinding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) is used

Comment: I am of the opinion, that while down-voting it becomes the duty of the down-voter to clarify the reason associated with it, to give some information to the Original seeker as well as the Original Poster, so that atleast they can justify their stand. Since no clarification was given, hence I find myself at the liberty to up-vote the answer to negate the cause, of the said action.